# WebAssembly module in a web worker, in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, web-worker, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I've been banging my head against this brick wall for 2 days now and I cannot figure it out. I'm trying to load my wasm module in a web worker in a Vue app and nothing I can find works. First, let me explain what does work. I can load my wasm module in the main thread (async) and then use it without any problems at all. However, as soon as I try to load it in a web worker it breaks. I set up a repo here so you can see the code:

https://github.com/mthelm85/wasm-web-worker

The error in the console is:

```
wasm.worker.worker.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="./permutations_bg.js" error: module is not an object or function
```

I'm building the module with wasm-pack and using the default target (bundler).

I assumed this was just a webpack issue but I've tried many different options (using @wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin, adding an experiments: { syncWebAssembly: true } to my webpack config, etc.) and none of them do the trick.

I would be extremely grateful to anyone who can assist in any way with figuring this out.

Comment: I get a 404 when I try to access your github link.